# Restricting gridview row selection in asp.net using c#.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, gridview

I have textbox and gridview(checkbox in Itemtemplate) in my webform.
my requirement  selecting checkbox in gridview must be restricted  based on value given in textbox i.e if textbox value is 10 then i can only be able to check 10 rows in gridview.
Can anybody give me `javascrit` for this or any other easy way....

Thanks in advance..
my code is below...

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
    function CheckBoxCount() {
        var gv = document.getElementById("<%= GridView1.ClientID %>");
        var inputList = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var textboxcount = document.getElementById("<%=txtId.ClientID %>").value;
        var numChecked = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++)
        {

            if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && inputList[i].checked)
            {
                alert(numChecked);
                if (numChecked < textboxcount)
                {
                    inp[i].checked = false;
                    alert(numChecked);
                }
                numChecked = numChecked + 1;
            }
        }


    }
</script>
```

I am trying in javascript

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >

    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate >


                <asp:CheckBox ID="chb" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onClick="CheckBoxCount()"   />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you the JS right away but try doing it this way.

put a class on your text box and check box, And then:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chb" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onClick="CheckBoxCount()" CssClass="MyCheckBox" />
```

Then in the javascript add a function onClick of checkBox:

```
$('.MyCheckBox').onClick(function(){
    var $allCheckBoxes = $('#GridView1').find('.MyCheckBox');
    var checkedCheckBoxes = 0;
    var allowedCheckBoxes = $('.NumberOfCheckBoxesClass').val();
    $allCheckBoxes.each(
        if($(this).Checked){
            checkedCheckBoxes++;
        }
    );

    if(checkedCheckBoxes > 10){
        $(this).disable;
        AND SHOW SOME MESSAGE letting the user know.
    }
});
```

You obviously need a few more methods to disable all the 
Let me know if you have any questiongs.